# Assign aws name identification to an ec2 instance using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I created an ec2 instance using Terraform code and added one tag. But I would like to add a default instance name as well to appear in the field shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

How do I do that using Terraform?.

Right now, I tried the `default` argument for the tag but did not seem to work. I find it hard to figure out from the [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance).

Code that I currently used to create it:

```
resource "aws_instance" "webserver" {
  ami = "ami-09a41e26df464c548"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    default = "my-ec2-instance"
    "Terraform" = "Yes"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to add a tag with the key of `Name`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "webserver" {
  ami = "ami-09a41e26df464c548"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "my-ec2-instance"
    "Terraform" = "Yes"
  }
}
```

The name of the instance will appear as such:

[image]